# Extending Django Admin to include related fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am attempting to extend Django admin to add related fields to model add/change form that can not be handled by Inlines.

My simplified model is as follows:

```
class Token(models.Model):
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=38, blank=False)

class Package(models.Model):
    tokens = models.ManyToManyField(Token)

class UserToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    token = models.ForeignKey(Token)
    value = #Some instance specific value
    expires = models.DateField(blank=False)

class UserPackage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    package = models.ForeignKey(Package)

    expires = models.DateField(blank=False)
```

What I need to do is when the UserPackage is being created to use the tokens ManyToMany relationship on Package to create UserTokens. Each UserToken may have different instance value.

It would be ideal to have tokens and value fields available to be filled out in the admin add/change page for UserPackage. The list needs to be pre-populated with all the possible entries which is why inlines don't seem like a good choice here.

**Current Solution**

1. Expect "?package=" param on add URL
2. overwrite ModelAdmin.add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None) to read the URL param and generate the list of token objects
3. extend the change_form template for model to create the
4. overwrite ModelAdmin.save_model(self, request, obj, form, change) to look through request.data[] to find added fields. (They won't actually show up in ModelForm of course).

**Question**

This works but seems extremely hacky. Is there a more clean solution to implement this in Django 1.4 ?

Comment: When it comes to bending the admin to do things it doesn't offer natively, unfortunately a lot of the approaches are hacky. You might be better off writing your own view and hooking it into the admin templates

Comment: Your 3 steps are exactly what one would need to do  to add more forms to the admin. I've done the same to force inline creation in the `add_view`. It's actually not all that hacky, since the `add_view` is just a view and you can handle whatever form logic you wish..

Comment: I suspect that Timmy is ultimately right. I found that for couple of fields it's a little more natural (over my original solution) to overwrite the get_form() and save_model() on ModelAdmin. This takes away the need to mess around with the templates.